# Différence entre « quelque chose est quelque part » et « il y a quelque chose quelque part »

Tags: usage

> Un homme est dans la cour.
>
> Il y a un homme dans la cour.

Peut-on employer ces deux propositions indifféremment l'une à la place de l'autre ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On peut être sûr d'une chose: dans la langue parlée les français utilisent « Il y a un homme dans la cour. » et s'ils utilisent l'autre possibilité ce ne peut être qu'assez rarement. Mais je ne vois aucune autre particularité; quant à ce de quoi il en retourne dans la langue écrite je n'en ai aucune idée.

Évidemment il y a un cas particulier pour lequel « un » n'est plus l'article indéfini mais l'adjectif numéral cardinal; dans ce cas où le nombre importe on utilise, bien sûr, la seconde possibilité, mais aussi la première.

Answer (score 1):

"il y a" renforce l'indétermination: il y a "un" homme;

d'autres parts, "est" renforce la détermination, "l'" homme (qu'on cherche, dont on parle) "est" dans la cour.

On ne dira pas "Il y a l'homme dans la cour" à moins d'un gros effet de rhétorique,

alors que c'est un peu moins fort comme contexte, mais ce serait quand même peu fréquent d'entendre "Un homme est dans la cour", à moins de récupérer un début de phrase qu'on a déjà commencée par "Un homme est …" et de finir la volonté de préciser qu'il est dans la cour.